# Post JSON Data From IOS to Remote MVC Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm looking to post json data to an mvc application via IOS device.
I wrote the application and tested it on local. It is working fine. But when I host the application on a remote server an exception occurred. Fiddler reports that the resource is not found.

I carry out some operations (add data to db, create some file etc) and return true or false.

My JSON Data Format

```
var data= { "param1": "something", "param2": "something" };
```

My Action

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PostActionData(DataModel model)
{
    ... some operations
    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

model is always null

```
 public class DataModel
 {
    public string param1 { get; set; }
    public string param2 { get; set; }
 }
```

I try from the remote server but it does not work. When I try from a local server with sample request it works.

My Sample Request is :

```
$.ajax({
        url: "url/controller/action",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        success: function (result) {
            alert("OK");
        }
});
```

What have I missed?

Comment: Maybe you have error in your url in production environment? Add in question the real url which used in $.ajax method.

Comment: Have you tried adding the [FromBody] attribute to your DataModel parameter?